# ServletContextListener isn't invoked when using com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, httpserver

I use `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer` in integration tests. It does its job but I've noticed that `ServletContextListener's` methods aren't invoked during tests.
When I deploy the app to the real Tomcat server I can see its methods being called.

Below is the listener class:

```
package abc;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

@WebListener
public class StartupListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        System.out.println("########################################");
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        System.out.println("########################################");
    }
}
```

Here is how I start the `HttpServer` in the test:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void startServer() {
    URI uri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/").port(8080).build();

    // Create an HTTP server listening at port 8080
    try {
        server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(uri.getPort()), 0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fail();
    }

    // Create a handler wrapping the JAX-RS application
    HttpHandler handler = RuntimeDelegate.getInstance().createEndpoint(new ApplicationConfig(), HttpHandler.class);
    // Map JAX-RS handler to the server root
    server.createContext(uri.getPath(), handler);
    // Start the server
    server.start();
}
```

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I removed     `@WebListener` and inserted

```
metadata-complete="false"
```

and

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>abc.StartupListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

in `web.xml` but it didn't help

What is the problem? Is there anything that needs to be setup?

Comment: I'm not sure if and how it is possible to create a servlet container with the `HttpServer` used here. Isn't that a use case for Jetty?

Comment: You seem to think that `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer` is a Servlet-compliant servlet container. It isn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the problem?

HttpServer is not a servlet container and does not know about servlet api.

> Is there anything that needs to be setup?

[You need to setup a servlet container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179746/unit-test-a-servlet-with-an-embedded-jetty#14181904) like jetty, which is frequently used for unit testing java based web applications.

Comment: Thank you. However I'll try it later as I've already created a unit-test that tests the listener class directly.

Comment: You are welcome. If this question is answered, please mark it answered. If you encounter issues on setting up sevlet container environment for JUnit testing, feel free to research or ask new questions on that topic.